# Is that possible to get attribute name from checkbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm wondering if this is possible to get the name of the `lightining-input` when the component loads and run the `isChecked` get method.

The reason behind is to, make a generic method instead of creating each get method for every checkbox.

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" name="status_chkbox" type="toggle"
                checked={isChecked}
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
```

JS

```
get isChecked() {
    //fetch from db value
    return true/false; //just an example.
    //find the name attribute?
}
```

Comment: why are you using a getter for the isChecked attribute? as opposed to  binding an onChange event handler to the input field?

Comment: I have `onChange` event handler but when the component loads I'm loading from database and showing check/uncheck state.

Comment: So, you have several input-fields, they need to be checked if they are true/false upon loading. Assuming you have a for:each iteration rendering the multiple input-fields which you have assigned to a property? why not use a template literal in your html ? otherwise, assign the propr from the iteration to the "checked" property of the input field?

Comment: I have a custom logic to run before I show true/false from database and for that reason I’m not using html for each

Comment: you can still run custom logic and depend on a for:each to properly handle rendering of records.

Comment: Custom logic on html? Can you show some sample code

Comment: custom logic on your properties/js code... your HTML should be reactive to property changes. not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters do not know why they are being called. For example, the getter would fire on:

```
console.log(this.isChecked);
```

Obviously, it would have no associated element.

Ordinarily, you'd just put all your data into an object and bind to that:

```
<lightning-input checked={record.field1} ...
```

Which would be stored in the controller as:

```
@track record = { field1: true, ... }
```

Comment: I'm trying to justify my use case if I'm following the right path, since I have lots of logic behind the scene I end-up using the getter method to process that logic and simple return once the logic is processed, so  again, I have 25 checkboxes and I will have a 25 get methods, which bothers me thinking that am I repeating the same code multiple times, any thoughts?

Comment: @NickKahn Do your calculations in an event handler, then update the relevant fields in the data object.

Comment: so even if I have the calculation in an event handler my logic will still not be valid because when the component loads I have to go grab the data from different source and then compare do validation and then show the checkbox checked/unchecked. it's not a happy path for sure.

Comment: @NickKahn You can write a common method to perform your calculations after loading data and on event changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how this extends to a getter/setter approach, but you should be able to have the function utilize an event parameter that you can access for data regarding the checkbox used, something similar to this:

```
get isChecked(event){
   const checkboxName = event.target.name;
   //helper value that tells you whether the checkbox is checked or not and acts accordingly
   const checkboxValue = event.target.checked;
   //do whatever else you need it to
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: You did not understand my question

Comment: checked is a Boolean attribute, not an event handler.